# css touch-action none on body, pinch-zoom on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply this:

```
body {
  touch-action: none;
}

.left-side {
  touch-action: pinch-zoom;
}

<div class="left-side"><img src="image.jpg" /></div>
```

The touch-action: none is working, but left-side is now :(

What am I doing wrong? Or does the body override everything?

Comment: You should include your HTML. Also note, there are (a few) elements which do not support `touch-action`.

Comment: Added my html to my question

Comment: So, basically what do you want to achieve? Touch-driven zooming with multiple-fingers is permitted. Can be combined with pan-x, pan-left or pan-right; and pan-y pan-up or pan-down. It is not possible in desktop version.

Comment: @CharmingZooZoo How do you actually... you know... pinch-zoom to zoom, not pan?

Answer (score 4):

The `touch-action` value `pinch-zoom`, is a modifier of sorts. According the [The MDN spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action), it is used in combination with other values:

> The `touch-action` property may be specified as either:
>
> - any one of the keywords `auto`, `none`, `manipulation`, **or**
> - one of the keywords `pan-x`, `pan-left`, `pan-right`, **and/or** one of the keywords `pan-y`, `pan-up`, `pan-down`, plus *optionally* the keyword `pinch-zoom`.

`pinch-zoom` does nothing on its own, it simply lets the browser know that it should allow two finger gestures to be used; to control the actions listed along with it.

So if you want to allow multi finger support to pan the page sideways, you would use:

```
.left-side {
   touch-action: pan-x pinch-zoom;
}
```

**Note:** Keep in mind that this functionality is only for touch devices; mouse and accessible systems won't reflect any functionality changes with it.

Comment: so are you saying you can't use `touch-action: pinch-zoom` to allow to actually pinch zoom the element?  to me that would seem to be the logical thing for it to do..

Comment: @MatthewMoore and how do you enable `pinch-zoom` with disabled `pan` functionality?

Comment: That would be zooming from the center of the element always, without panning (moving it while zoomed)

Answer (score 2):

These properties are not really what they look to be:

> *The **touch-action** CSS property allows a developer to restrict how a user can interact with an element which is especially helpful to
> prevent events being dispatched when it's not necessary.*

You cannot really add any touch interaction that was not there already, but you can restrict touch interactions that are there if you need to. So what does the `pinch-zoom` do then?

> If you pinch on a website it'll generally zoom in on the pages
> content. Defining a touch-action will prevent this behavior, but
> adding pinch-zoom will re-enable this behavior.

I am not aware of any pinch-zoom CSS solution, but it's doable with a bit of javascript (`touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend` give you all you need). There are also libraries providing convenient wrappers for common gestures, like [hammerjs](http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/).

You can read more about touch-action [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/touch-action).